# Show files from 2 different folders in a single Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, .net-4.0, directoryinfo

Is it possible to show files from 2 different folders (c:\test1 and c:\test2) in the same gridview?

I work in VB.net (VS 2010)

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by show? load them? display their paths strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Get list of all the files using `Directory.GetFiles()` into a single `IEnumerable<string>` and bind it to a GridView.

This is how you'll do it in c#.

```
            List<string> allFiles = new List<string>();
            allFiles.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\test1\*"));
            allFiles.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\test2\*"));

            yourGV.DataSource = allFiles;
            yourGV.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
Dim files As New List(Of String)()
files.AddRange(GetAllFilesFromDir("C:\foo")) 
files.AddRange(GetAllFilesFromDir("C:\bar"))
'GetAllFilesFromDir() must return IEnumerable string
gv.DataSource = files
gv.DataBind()

<asp:gridview ID="gv" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="file" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

You hadn't shown your code in your question, so the above example demonstrates how this might be done generally.

Comment: Thanks, but is not working, I use VB and convert this code to something like this:

`Dim archivos As New List(Of String)()

archivos.AddRange(GetAllFilesFromDir("C:\Temp")
archivos.AddRange(GetAllFilesFromDir("C:\Temp2")`

And get a error in GetAllFilesFromDir

Comment: @Andrés: please mention VB.NET when it's required. Hopefully the edit above will help!

Comment: Not working, say "GetAllFilesFromDir is not declared" and "Generate method stub" and "Generate property stub"

Comment: `GetAllFilesFromDir` is a ficticious method I've assumed that you've got that takes care of enumerating a given directory's files. In my example, it'll return a string array. It takes care of converting the FileInfo array to string array.

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't know much of VB, but i will try to write the code.

`Private Function GetAllFilesFromDir(ByVal p1 As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function`

Comment: Is not working, the code is this:

`Private Function GetAllFilesFromDir(ByVal p1 As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
        Dim arch As New DirectoryInfo(p1)
        Dim archList As FileInfo() = arch.GetFiles()
        Return archList.ToList()
        Throw New Exception

    End Function`

Answer (score 0):

yes.  Add them both as collections to List() or any other collection type.  Then bind that set to the gridview.