# Asp.net: Show files from 2 different folders in a single Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show files from 2 different folders in a single Gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309182/show-files-from-2-different-folders-in-a-single-gridview)

Is it possible to show files from 2 different folders (c:\test1 and c:\test2) in the same gridview?

I work in VB.net (VS 2010)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Get list of all the files using `Directory.GetFiles()` into a single `IEnumerable<string>` and bind it to a GridView.

Comment: Can you help me writing the code, please... 'cause i lost all the morning and this don't work... please...

Comment: Why are you asking the same question twice? I've answered this in your other question with a c# sample.